# Some Holes formed when water is put on flat plate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

[image]

Why such holes are formed when we put water on a plate

What is the relation can be derived between h(height of standing water) and r(radius of hole).(if P₀ is atmospheric pressure,σ is surface tension between water and container,σ₀ surface tension between fluid molecules,μ being coefficient of static friction,g acceleration due to gravity and ρ₀ is fluid density and any other constant if required)?

What all forces we need to consider while solving this problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first guess it will be the result of [surface tension of the water](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/surten.html) , and irregularities on the plate allowing [bubbles to form](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/surten2.html#c1) when the water is poured.

Comment: Does it depend on atmospheric pressure also

Comment: The size  does, if you read the links

Comment: can you please give relation between h and r in this case.